# How to train bixby capsule to do voice recognition of amounts or values in millions, billions, etc?

Tags: bixby

When amounts or decimal numbers are collected, bixby voice recognizes 5 million as 5. What is the best way to train bixby to handle numbers in million or billions?

I am taking input for amounts. When Amount is in Million (say 5 million), bixby voice recognition treats it as 5 instead of 5 million.

When user says 5 million, bixby should recognize the number as 5,000,000. Instead it recognizes it as 5

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is I managed to do it with strings.

My javascript file was a file named magic.js that looked something like this:

```
module.exports.function = function magic (number, multiplier) {
  var mult
  var num = number.toString()

  if (multiplier == "millions" || multiplier == "million") {
    console.log (multiplier)
    mult = ",000,000"
  }
  else if (multiplier == "billions" || multiplier == "billion") {
    mult = ",000,000,000"
  }
  else if (multiplier == "trillions" || multiplier == "trillion") {
    mult = ",000,000,000,000"
  }
  return num.concat(mult)
}
```

in actions I made a model file that looks like this:

```
action (bignumber) {
  description (bignumber)
  collect {
    input (number) {
      type (number)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
    input (multiplier) {
      type (multiplier)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (answer)
  type (Calculation)
}
```

Made concepts that line up with the variables I needed. 
First a text one representing things like millions, billions etc.
Second a number as an integer. 
Third a text based answer.

Then I did some training where I had it train on multiplier (i.e. millions) and number (i.e. 5).

The end result was when I asked it to show me 5 million it would output 5,000,000

Comment: Thanks. Did you try anything with vocab to handle this?